# Django: Create and Update seperate objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

In Django models, I aim to ensure that when I create an object from one class, the corresponding object is created in another class. Furthermore, certain fields should be automatically inherited. Here's an example:

```
`class Model1(models.Model):

  Malfunction  = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.Malfunction


class Model2(models.Model):
    sit_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    given_Malfunctions = models.ManyToManyField(Model1, blank=True)       
    dynamik_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"[{self.sit_id:02d}]"

class Model3(models.Model):
    connection_to_model2 = models.ForeignKey(Model2, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    dynamik_3 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, blank=True)
```

`

Model3 object should be created every time a Model2 object got created. And the fields from dynamik_2 should be automatically updated to dynamik_3.

Should i define the signals or functions in model 3? I encountered an issue with "post_save" since I couldn't establish the connection between related objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the save method for `Model2` and `Model3`.

*Model3 object should be created every time a Model2 object got created*

```py
class Model2(models.Model):
    sit_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    given_Malfunctions = models.ManyToManyField(Model1, blank=True)       
    dynamik_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"[{self.sit_id:02d}]"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._state.adding: # This is true if there is a NEW object being created, not an existing one being updated
            super().save(*args, **kwargs) # Save the object to the database
            new_model3 = Model3.objects.create(connection_to_model2=self) # Self contains the current object
```

*the fields from dynamik_2 should be automatically updated to dynamik_3*

I'm assuming you mean that when `dynamik_3` gets updated, `dynamik_2` should reflect the same value? It looks easier imho to just get the value from `model3` directly, instead of keeping track of two fields who will contain the same values. Anyways, if you still want to go ahead with it, you could do something like this:

```py
class Model3(models.Model):
    connection_to_model2 = models.ForeignKey(Model2, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    dynamik_3 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.connection_to_model2: # If there is a connection
            self.connection_to_model2.dynamik_2 = self.dynamik_3
            self.connection_to_model2.save()
        
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: i actually want to update dynamik_3 only, when dynamik_2 gets changed.

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to solve this issue with using 2 @receiver methods:

```
# Signal to create Model3 object and copy dynamik_2 to dynamik_3
@receiver(post_save, sender=Model2)
def create_model3_and_copy_fields(sender, instance, created, 
**kwargs):
    if created:
        Model3.objects.create(connection_to_model2=instance, 
dynamik_3=instance.dynamik_2)

# Signal to update dynamik_3 when dynamik_2 in Model2 changes
@receiver(post_save, sender=Model2)
def update_model3_dynamik_3(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        model3_obj = 
Model3.objects.get(connection_to_model2=instance)
        model3_obj.dynamik_3 = instance.dynamik_2
        model3_obj.save()
    except Model3.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```